# What could it mean if I can't connect to google.com but a traceroute shows no issues?

Tags: networking

At my workplace, we can currently connect to some sites but not others, all computers on the network have the same issue, so it can't be device specific.

I can connect to Apple.com, but not Google.com. A traceroute and pings to Google.com, however, go through just fine.

With this information, can the issue be pinpointed? What can the problem be?

Additional detail: rebooting the router caused sites to work again for 60 second intervals.

And no, my workplace doesn't block sites.

Comment: Traceroute (sometimes UDP, sometimes ICMP), ping (ICMP) and HTTP (TCP) are very different in just about all respects except that they all operate on top of IP. The most important diagnostic step you can take is probably to determine where on your network (if anywhere) the problem is introduced: take a laptop, and move closer and closer to the network perimeter (the uplink connection). Find out where the problem disappears. The device immediately on the inside of your network from there is likely to be the culprit.

Comment: Ask your IT staff.

Comment: @DavidPostill Im a computer enthusiast myself and am intetested in learning about such networking scenarios personally, hence asking on SuperUser

Comment: @ColorQuestor It's possible that your IT department have blocked access to certain websites ...

Comment: As stated there can be a numerous sources to this specific problem, since plain simple blocked websites, to IP related.  On this last, I've often stumbled on MTU when using Linux routers doing NAT, ending in this very behaviour, some sites open, and others don't.

Comment: "With this information, can the issue be pinpointed?" Nope. :)  Talk to your company's IT that set up your Internet access.

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, he (our tech department) didnt know what the issue was either.

Answer (score 1):

Ping, traceroute and websites work on different network layers. Ping sends ICMP requests (Network Layer), traceroute sends UDP packets (Transport Layer), and websites use HTTP requests (Application Layer).

For more about layers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Description_of_OSI_layers

So, your network is blocking some requests only on higher layers. Your network might be blocked, for example, by proxies, filters, and firewalls.

--

Now the issue seems related to your router or after it. I can think of these problems:

1. Router is overheating;
2. Cable is not connected or is not working properly;
3. Router with bad configuration (like a strange DNS, for example);
4. ISP is blocking for some reason.